# Произношение и фонетическая транскрипция слова шестьдесят

Tags: фонетика, транскрипция

При быстрой речи мы обычно произносим числительное **60** как [шыс'ат], а если помедленнее, то [шыз'д'эс'ат].
Является ли моя запись правильной (для школы/института в отдельности), и какие еще существуют варианты (например, фонематический, с примерами двух известных направлений).

Comment: >Фонематическая транскрипция передает каждое слово по составу фонем, **не отражая возникающих в слабых позициях вариантов и вариаций.** Она применяется в записях примеров и парадигм грамматики, где важна структурная, а не произносительная сторона дела. Ее принцип: каждая фонема независимо от позиции изображается **всегда одним и тем же знаком**.

Посмотрим, как на самом деле :  
![юность](http://edu.grsu.by/books/kavinkina_fonetika/images/sampledata/kartinki/formula.jpg)  
Фонематическая схема слова **юность** : на месте звука с' обнаруживаем дробь с четырьмя вариантами! Вопрос : зачем?

Comment: Звуков з и з' близко не бывает в произношении слова *юность*, его падежных и однокоренных форм. Зачем эта ужасная дробь в разборе, **для пущей важности**?? А как же тогда быть с "одним и тем же знаком для фонемы". Поставьте знак <з>, будьте последовательны и не морочьте людям головы.

Comment: Дерзкий grantum, мне кажется, вы несправедливы к науке фонологии. И что это за страшный зверь изображен у Вас в скобках? Наверное, гиперфонема?  Так с ними лучше не иметь дела - они придуманы для развития студенческого и научного мышления. Гиперфонемы находятся в непроверяемых позициях звуков. Так, в слове юность мягкий звук С может представлять 4 разных фонемы. Это такой обобщенный зубный смычной звук, который не различается по звонкости/глухости, мягкости/твердости. В практической орфографии это понятие не находит применения.

Comment: Термины фонематическая и фонетическая транскрипция - это представление слова в виде звуковой записи. Например, берем слово ёж. Фонетическая транскрипция - это обычная транскрипция, передающая реальное звучание слова: j о ш. Фонематическая транскрипция - это фонемная запись слова: j о ж. При фонематической транскрипции мы как бы переходим от буквы к звуку согласно правилам графики. Фонемная запись слова - это звуковая запись слова без учета фонетического чередования (орфографическое чтение).

Comment: Схему не я написал, она является примером фонематического разбора из сети. Напишите вместо <jу'но с,с'/з,з' т'> свою схему. Что будет вместо дроби? Зачем в разборе конкретного слова писать все возможные варианты фонем, которые может обозначать в этом положении буква/звук С. В слове стоит буква С, произносим С', какого лешего надо приводить **все фонемы**? Тренировка такая, значит. Смешно.  
<шэс'т'д'эс'ат>

Comment: Я тоже за <шэс'т'д'эс'ат>, считаю, что это и есть фонематическая транскрипция, и она полностью соответствует буквенной записи с учетом правил графики. Может быть, кто-то считает, что если звук нельзя проверить (привести к сильной позиции), то там обязательно не фонема, а гиперфонема. Но буквами мы обозначаем фонемы, а не гиперфонемы - мы же  пишем буквы, а не дробь из букв. Выбор С нельзя проверить, но он сделан - это фонема С.

Comment: Вот определение из википедии: Фонематическая транскрипция (также фонемная или фонологическая) — система передачи звучания слов письменными и некоторыми условными знаками, отражающая лишь фонемы этих слов, без учёта их аллофонов. Так что фонемная запись зависит от цели.Если вы хотите подробно описать слабую позицию звука, то можно использовать гиперфонему, но это интересно только в качестве упражнения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разговорное произношение [шыс'ат],

литературное : школа младшие классы:[шыз'д'ис'ат].Ударение ещё поставить.

старшие-[шъз'д'и(с призвуком э)с'ат].

фонематическая - <шэс'т'- д'эс'ат>, московская и с-петербургская фонологические школы отличаются отношением к фонеме Ы-москвичи не признают её за отдельную фонему и обозначают как И: вазы <ва-зи >, в этом слове(шестьдесят) их позиции совпадают.

Институтская сложнее - с аккомодацией и т.д.. Здесь не получится написать, ресурс не позволяет вставить символы.А вообще транскрипций много самых разных в зависимости от целей, все не перечесть, много альтернативных. Ищите по сайтам, если очень интересуетесь.

Comment: А что там дефис означает?

Comment: В фонематической транскрипции запись идёт поморфемно, ведь она показывает строение слова

Answer (score 0):

Дерзкий grantum, а где же фотография гиперфонемы в слове шестьдесят? Это же уникальный случай: звук Т находится в позиции, где сходятся значения 4 фонем, да еще НУЛЕВОЙ ВАРИАНТ в придачу. Как бы всё это записать?

Comment: Можно поспрошать на лингвофоруме мнение знатоков, попробую.

Comment: И еще.Из Википедии:  «Фонематическая транскрипция  — система передачи звучания слов письменными  знаками, отражающая лишь фонемы этих слов, без учёта их аллофонов».  
Но это в том случае, если можно  определить фонему путем проверки – тогда можно выделить доминанту и аллофоны.  А если нельзя? Вот в слове шестьдесят два непроверяемых согласных С и Т, которые произносятся как мягкий звук З.  Их  можно записать в виде буквенных сочетаний (СТ, СД, СЬТ и т.д.), а также можно использовать не четыре  буквы, а две буквы З/С – количество этих вариантов только математики могут подсчитать.

Comment: И всем разным буквенным вариантам будут соответствовать разные фонематические транскрипции.
Соответственно, из этого следует, что  сначала нужно дать точное и полное определение  фонематической транскрипции, а потом делать ее запись. Решение здесь может быть очень простое: определять фонему в непроверяемой позиции по букве, например: <вокзал>. Но принять такое простое решение как-то никто не решается – слишком много всяких теорий будет поставлено под сомнение.